# C# Xamarin Recieve and Display image from Stream Byte Array with TCP Sockets

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, websocket

I am currently working on a project that **I send an Image through TCP** using sockets **from a WinForm** Application **to a Xamarin Android** App in the **same network**.

I've tested the Server ( WinForms ) code using a client ( also Winforms) and managed it to work. But **the problem comes**, when I code **for Android client** in Xamarin I find out that I cannot use Bitmap the same way, so **I tried to find other ways.**

The problem is with the android Client code. I've checked in debugging that the image **bytes get all through** from Server -> Client.

**On the Android Client :**
If I remove the `while loop` and start playing with the Send button ( server) and Connect Button(Client) some images show up on the clients side. *That's odd*

*I am not an expert on these matters so feel free to suggest any corrections*

**The codes that I use**

The Code in my **WinForms Server** is this.

```
private void StartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 9999);
         Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
         server.Bind(iep);
         server.Listen(100);
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client....");
         client = server.Accept();
     }
     private void SendImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Bitmap bmp = TakingScreenshotEx1(); // method for taking screenshot
         bmp.Save("1.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); // the name of the screenshot taken, just before 
    
         byte[] buffer = ReadImageFile("1.jpeg"); // read the saved image file 
         int v = client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None); // send the image 
         Console.WriteLine("Image SENT!");
     }
```

My **WinForms Client** ( newbie but working method )

```
 IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 9999);
     Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
    
     private async void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {  
        if(client.Connected != true)
         client.Connect(iep);
    
         await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingLong());
     }
    private async void DoSomethingLong()
     {
         while (true)
         {
             int v = client.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
             Console.WriteLine("Data Received!");
    
             Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
             var img = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
             pictureBox1.Image = img;
         }
     }
```

The problematic **Android Client**

```
     IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 9999);
     Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
     private async void Connect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (client.Connected != true)
             client.Connect(iep);

         await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingLong());
     }
     public Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource PhotoStream { get; set; }
     private async void DoSomethingLong()
     {

         while(true){
             int v = client.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                 Console.WriteLine("Data Received!");
                 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                if (stream != null)
                     imgXam.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
         }
}
```

Comment: use MainThread when updating your ImageSource - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your response . That's clearly seems to do something. But if I put a `while loop`, and the code inside it. So it refreshes automatically. The App freezes ( suppose the loop is blocking the UI Thread), which is the problem that led me that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Following `@Jason`'s advice and putting the `Invoke Method` inside a `Timer` . I was able to solve the problem

```
 Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), () =>
        {
            // called every 1 second

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

            });
            
            return true; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
            
        });
```